# PostConstruct and test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit

I use spring boot 3

Main spring boot class

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class FlexApplication{

    private final ApplicationParameterManager appParamManager;

    public FlexApplication(ApplicationParameterManager appParamManager) {
        this.appParamManager = appParamManager;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){

    }

    ....

}


@Service
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationParameterManager{
....
}
```

Basic test

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest
public class ListUserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ListUserRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void getListUserByUserType(){
        String typeUser = "CETEST";

        Pageable page =  Pageable.ofSize(10);

        Page<ListUser> pageListUser = repository.findAllByTypeUser(typeUser, page);
        assertThat(pageListUser.getContent().size() > 5 ).isTrue();

    }


}
```

Otherwise this test, application run well

I get this error

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.acme.FlexApplication required a bean
> of type 'com.acme.parameter.ApplicationParameterManager' that could
> not be found.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not related to version of Spring Boot.

As you're using `@DataJpaTest` , your bean is not created

[Spring Docs:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.autoconfigured-spring-data-jpa)

> @DataJpaTest can be used if you want to test JPA applications. By
> default it will configure an in-memory embedded database, scan for
> @Entity classes and configure Spring Data JPA repositories. Regular
> @Component beans will not be loaded into the ApplicationContext.

Solution would be to use `@SpringBootTest` instead of `@DataJpaTest` if your test is not really a JPA test.

Also, still using `@DataJpaTest` you could add `@Import(ApplicationParameterManager.class)` to your test class

Answer (score 1):

When using @DataJpaTest, you are not creating the whole spring context as when you run the application normally but you only create the beans responsible for data access layer.

In order to run your tests properly, you need to provide a mocked bean of type `ApplicationParameterManager`.
The easiest way to do it is by utilizing `@MockBean annotation`.

So, to make your tests work, edit the test in the following way.

```
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace= AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@DataJpaTest
public class ListUserRepositoryTest {
    @MockBean
    private ApplicationParameterManager applicationParameterManager;
    @Autowired
    private ListUserRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void getListUserByUserType(){
        String typeUser = "CETEST";

        Pageable page =  Pageable.ofSize(10);

        Page<ListUser> pageListUser = repository.findAllByTypeUser(typeUser, page);
        assertThat(pageListUser.getContent().size() > 5 ).isTrue();

    }
}
```

That way, the spring context will include a mocked bean of your required dependency.

Take a look at `@MockBean` java doc for more information. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/MockBean.html

If you prefer to run the whole spring context in order to perform full integration tests, take a look at `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

`@DataJpaTest` should be used when you want to test data access layer in isolation.